# How to Backup old website data to new server

Tags: wordpress, web

How can i update old backup data of my website to new server. which tools should i used to upload backup or is there manual to do it?

Comment: I'd suggest looking over at [wordpress.se] since a common topic like this should have existing answers for this.

Comment: I personally use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration

Answer (score 0):

Many way to move old backup to new server but i prefer All in one migration plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: I would not recommend using this plugin as there are serious size limits - once you hit the limit you have to purchase PRO.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please do more research before asking a question. This question has been asked probably over a million times before.

Official guide: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/
Guide: https://wpengine.com/resources/migrate-wordpress-site/
Guide: https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/
Guide: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-host-or-server-with-no-downtime/

I can list the links forever...

Here is how I would do it:

1. Log in to FTP and download the root folder with all website files (the folder is usually called `html` or `htdocs`).
2. Login to phpMyAdmin (if you don't have phpMyAdmin you can use MySQLWorkbench) and export the database.
   2.1. If there are multiple databases, you will have to check wp-config.php `define( 'DB_NAME', 'DATABASE_NAME' );`.

Now do the same with new hosting just in reverse.

1. Log in to FTP and upload your website files to root directory.
2. Log in to phpMyAdmin and create a new database and then import the exported database. Make sure to create a user with correct permissions for that database.
   (optional: if your domain changes as well make sure to change it in wp_options table)
3. Edit wp-config.php - enter new details for the db name, db user and user password.
4. DONE

You can also use a plugin for that but most of these type of plugins are paid or have limits on how much you can export etc.